# Installing clarifai (grpc) failed, exit status 1

Tags: python, windows, grpc, clarifai

What version of gRPC and what language are you using? 
lastest
What operating system (Linux, Windows,...) and version? 
Windows 10 Server
What runtime / compiler are you using (e.g. python version or version of gcc) python
What did you do?
Tried to install it from pip install command

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:  command:
>   'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe'
>   -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-6hv8xzb8\grpcio\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-6hv8xzb8\grpcio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-nkilt9xu\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>        cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-6hv8xzb8\grpcio\
>   Complete output (66 lines): Found cython-generated files... running
>   install running build running build_py running build_project_metadata
>   creating python_build creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8 creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_auth.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc
>   copying src\python\grpcio\grpc_channel.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_common.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc
>   copying src\python\grpcio\grpc_compression.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_grpcio_metadata.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_interceptor.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_plugin_wrapping.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_server.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc
>   copying src\python\grpcio\grpc_utilities.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc
>   creating python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\implementations.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\interfaces.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\utilities.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta_client_adaptations.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta_metadata.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta_server_adaptations.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\beta creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\gevent.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\session_cache.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc_cython copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_cython__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc_cython creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\aio_channel.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\aio_server.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\aio__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\experimental\aio creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\cardinality.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\style.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\common creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\abandonment.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\callable_util.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\future.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\logging_pool.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream_util.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\base.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\utilities.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\face.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\utilities.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc_cython_cygrpc copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_cython_cygrpc__init__.py ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc_cython_cygrpc creating
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc_cython_credentials copying
>   src\python\grpcio\grpc_cython_credentials\roots.pem ->
>   python_build\lib.win32-3.8\grpc_cython_credentials running build_ext
>   error: [WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato
>   ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe'
>   -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-6hv8xzb8\grpcio\setup.py'"'"';
>   file='"'"'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-6hv8xzb8\grpcio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-nkilt9xu\install-record.txt'
>   --single-v

ersion-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Expected to install it as it did on my personal computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC team has an issue to track adding 3.8 pre-compiled wheels https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20615. Currently, 3.8 wheels are only available in Linux, but not for Windows or macOS. I would recommend:

1. Switch to CPython 3.7;
2. Help the community by digging into the compilation error.